# Not able to click on a link a java link on a site using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

After opening the site there is a frame inside that frame menubar is their and in that menubar 5 button are their for example:-

Search (with e underlined and a drop down arrow also with search) and Window (with W underlined a drop down arrow also with window) I want to click on search.

I tried using `href,id` but unable to click on search.

```
        $Url = “some site” 
        $Username=”xxx” 
        $Password=”xxx” 

       $IE = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application; 
       $IE.visible = $true; 
       $IE.navigate($url); 
       while ($IE.Busy -eq $true) 

      { 

      Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 2000; 

      }

        $IE.Document.getElementById(“USERNAME”).value = $Username 
         $IE.Document.getElementByID(“PIN”).value=$Password 
        $IE.Document.getElementById(“HardcodedSub”).Click()

        while($ie.busy) {sleep 5} 

        $Link = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("a") | where-object {$_.id -eq     'menu_2'}
         $Link.click()


error:-You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:25 char:1
+ $Link.click()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull


inspect element:-

<a id="menu_2" tabindex="2" class="menu_unselected_text" href="javascript:window.parent.role_main.cai_main.setActKeyMenuState(2)">S<u>e</u>arch<img border="0" src="/CAisd/img/arrow_asc_bk.png" width="15" height="10"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why cant below line use the same GetElementById().

```
$Link = $ie.Document.getElementById("menu_2")
```

And its good to debug in PowerShell ISE or execute line by line and see the page loads completely before you call a method.

Regards,

Kvprasoon